# Dynamically create form and post to IFrame using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, forms, http-post

I have a page with a link and an IFrame on the page. On click of the link, I create a form around it and then post it. This is what I am doing:

```
elem.wrap('<form id="fooForm" name="fooForm" action = " do.php " target = "fooIframe" method="post" />')
$('#fooForm').submit();
```

The form posts and opens in new page and not in IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds terrifying, but all you need is an iframe to target with your link

```
<iframe name=blah></iframe>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="blah>
```

Answer (score -1):

What are you doing that for... do it properly using some ajax:

```
$.post('go.php',$("#fooForm").serialize(), function(response){
    $("#result").html(response)
})
```

Comment: I HAVE to use iframe for some security reasons. earlier i was just populating the href of the link inside the src attr of the iframe. but even that has some concerns so what i thought of doing is wrapping a form around the link and then posting the form to ifrae.